# Woocommerce programmatic add to order with product add-on

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I'm using WooCommerce Product Add-ons. I'm currently generating an order programmatically, but now need to include some Add-on data as part of the line item. How can this be done?

My basic order setup is like so:

```
$orderData = array(
            'status' => 'on-tab',
            'customer_id' => 999,
            'customer_note' => '',
            'created_via' => 'api'
        );
$order = wc_create_order($orderData);

foreach ($lineitems as $lineitem) {
    //need to get Add-On data in here somehow
    $order->add_product(wc_get_product(999), 1);
}
```

Comment: Can you please share your code, which you use to add product to cart?

Comment: I added an example, but it's mostly irrelevant because the person capable of answering the question would already be vary familiar with the code.

Comment: Do you want me to answer this or not? I am aware about sample code. But in WC there are many ways to do this and I need to know which way you are following.

Comment: Let me know so as I can look further.

Comment: Can you see my edit?

Comment: Yes. I can. But if you want me to help than please be sophisticated. I am helping you so don't be rude, please.

Comment: Sorry bud. Do you have access to the plugin code? Or have you worked with this one before?

Comment: I have developed lot of WC plugins. Do you want to have a look at one of my plugin?

Comment: I have found answer. Adding this in answer section...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use add_product, you will get item_id in return. See code from https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/source-class-WC_Abstract_Order.html#838-889

This item_id you can use to get item using get_item function. Refer https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/source-class-WC_Abstract_Order.html#760-769

Than after getting item you can add item meta using add_meta_data function. Refer code from https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/source-class-WC_Data.html#315-332

Combining all below is sample code :-

```
$orderData = array(
        'status' => 'on-tab',
        'customer_id' => 999,
        'customer_note' => '',
        'created_via' => 'api'
    );
$order = wc_create_order($orderData);

foreach ($lineitems as $lineitem) {
    //need to get Add-On data in here somehow
    $item_id = $order->add_product(wc_get_product(999), 1);
    $item = $order->get_item($item_id);
    $item->add_meta_data( 'Label', 'Value', true );
}
```

Hope this helps... Let me know if you need anything else...

Comment: Okay, that seems reasonable. I did find a matching line in the plugin that supports this: $item->add_meta_data( $key, $addon['value'] ); Now I just need to figure out the plugin's meta key format.

Comment: I'll be able to test it fully tonight. In order to fully complete the answer I need to find the right meta key used by the Product Add-ons plugin.

Comment: Note: $item = get_item($item_id); should be $item = $order->get_item($item_id); This code is not entirely working. The order is created with lineitem, but the meta data is not stored. I need to debug a bit to see what's going on.

Comment: Ok. I see.

"but the meta data is not stored." This seems to be some plugin bug. If you want than I am happy to help you as paid work. If not than you need to provide me some more details, if you need my help.

Comment: Okay, it works if you add this after adding the meta data: $item->save_meta_data();

Comment: I didn't understand "Okay, it works if you add this after adding the meta data: $item->save_meta_data();" Actually I have one plugin on codecanyon.net ( https://codecanyon.net/item/woocommerce-category-discount/20332051 ) And I just using add_meta_data and it do works.

Other fix, I have added...